# Unit Test action dispatch using enzyme

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form, enzyme, ava

I'm trying to write a simple unit test to make sure if the form inside a react component dispatches the expected action on submit.

Code:

Form submit action inside the component which I'm trying to test:

```
   <form onSubmit={(values, dispatch) => {  
        store.dispatch(doSomething());
        handleSubmit(values, dispatch);
    }}>
```

Test:

```
test('Test', (t) => {
const TestForm = TestForm();//redux form
const dispatchSpy = sinon.spy();

const props = Object.assign({}, baseProps, {
    handleSubmit: (callback) => {
        callback({}, dispatchSpy);
    },
});
t.context.form = mount(<Provider store={store}><TestForm /></Provider>);
t.context.form.find('form').simulate('submit');
//TODO - assert
```

The problem here is I get the following error and I'm not able to figure out the issue:

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Any thoughts on this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you passing props into your component? like this: `<TestForm {...props}/>`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to test form dispatches the expected action on submit ? I feel like it's just rewriting the internal test of redux-form (which is already tested here : 
[https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/**tests**/Form.spec.js#L131-L-165](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/__tests__/Form.spec.js#L131-L-165) )

Comment: Yes I'm interested to verify if the expected action is dispatched.